# Lower bounding $v^TA^{\dagger}v$ where A is a sum of rank-1 matrices

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces, upper-lower-bounds

This is related to a previous question I asked  ([Upper bounding $v^TAv$ where $A$ is the inverse of a sum of rank-$1$ matrices and $v$ is a vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4724207/upper-bounding-vtav-where-a-is-the-inverse-of-a-sum-of-rank-1-matrices-an)).
Let $(x_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n}$ be vectors of $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that at least one of them is not the zero vector. Let $A=\sum_{i}x_ix_i^T$ and $v \in \operatorname{Im}(A)$ .

In the previous post, I show that when  $A$ is invertible, a lower bound of $v^TA^{-1}v$ can be found by noticing that $A  \preceq \left(\sum_{i} x_i^Tx_i\right)I_d$, which yields $A^{-1} \succeq \left(\sum_{i} x_i^Tx_i\right)^{-1}I_d$ and $$v^TA^{-1}v \geq \left(\sum_{i} x_i^Tx_i\right)^{-1}v^Tv.$$

I would like to generalize this result to the case where $A$ is not necessarily invertible (replacing the true inverse by the pseudo-inverse). I understand this won't be true for every vector $v$ because of this negative result ([Is it true that $A\geq B$ implies $B^{\dagger}\geq A^{\dagger}$ for singular positive semi-definite matrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2076363/is-it-true-that-a-geq-b-implies-b-dagger-geq-a-dagger-for-singular-pos)), but I wonder if my additional assumption $v \in \operatorname{Im}(A)$ is enough to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $v \in \operatorname{Im}(A)$, there exists $y \in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $v=Ay$.
We have $v^TA^{\dagger}v=y^TAA^{\dagger}Ay=y^TAy.$
Let $\lambda_1 \geq \dots \lambda_d \geq 0$ be the eigenvalues of $A$. Since $A$ is symmetric, there is an orthonormal basis $\left(e_1,\dots,e_d\right)$ of eigenvectors of $A$, and we can write $y=\sum_{i=1}^{d} \alpha_ie_i.$

Then, $v=Ay=\sum_{i=1}^d \alpha_i\lambda_ie_i$ which gives $y^TAy=\sum_{i=1}^d \alpha_i^2 \lambda_i$ and $v^Tv=\sum_{i=1}^d \alpha_i^2\lambda_i^2$.
Furthermore, $v^Tv=\sum_{i=1}^d \alpha_i^2\lambda_i^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^d \alpha_i^2\lambda_i\lambda_1=\lambda_1y^TAy$ and we finally get $$v^TA^{\dagger}v \geq \lambda_1^{-1}v^Tv \geq Tr(A)^{-1}v^Tv = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^Tx_i\right)^{-1}v^Tv.$$